# Appium is not finding element when using a method to find it from a python appium class that inherits from a selenium class

Tags: python, automation, appium

Appium is not finding element with MobileBy Accessibility ID and I'm calling the method from AppiumDriver class that inherits from the SeleniumDriver class. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being, I had to use MobileBy.ID not MobileBy.Accessibility_ID and the element was found. The framework code was not an issue. Just using wrong locator type.